# Unable to install lavaan package

Tags: r

I was trying to install the `lavaan` package but I encounter the following error message. Do you have any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Joseph

```
install.packages("lavaan")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/abc/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/lavaan_0.5-14.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 572076 bytes (558 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 284 Kb
Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
   cannot open the connection

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 290913 != reported length 572076
2: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
3: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'lavaan/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Comment: Does this issue replicate if you try it again?  Also, what version of R are you using?

Comment: I was able to download and install **lavann** from http://cran.rstudio.org.

Comment: When I install I always use dependencies=TRUE and pkg:lavaan has quite a few: ` ‘qgraph’, ‘lisrelToR’, ‘rockchalk’, ‘lavaan.survey’, ‘semPlot’, ‘semTools’, ‘simsem’`.